# yii update bootstrap tdgridview after delete via ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to update my `yii bootstrap gridview` after i deleted a row using a ajax call from a modal onlick action;

So, I am not using the gridview delete button as you can see;

I actually used `e.preventDefault()` and opened a modal:

```
$('.delete_modal').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#myModalConfirmDelete #confirmDelete').data('id', $(this).data('id'));
                $('#myModalConfirmDelete #confirmDelete').data('type_domain_or_url', $(this).data('type_domain_or_url'));
            });
```

this code is for the modal `onclick` event:

```
$('#myModalConfirmDelete #confirmDelete').on('click', function() {

                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var type = $(this).data('type_domain_or_url');

                $.ajax({
                    url: url + '/user/' + type + '/delete',
                    data: {'id': id},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('domain-m-grid');
                        $('#myModalConfirmDelete').modal('hide');
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                });

            });
```

I need to code something else and replace the:

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('domain-m-grid');
```

If I would have used the standard yii gridview delete action, this code would have been executed:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery(document).on('click','#domain-m-grid a.delete',function() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;
    var th = this,
        afterDelete = function(){};
    jQuery('#domain-m-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        type: 'POST',
        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#domain-m-grid').yiiGridView('update');
            afterDelete(th, true, data);
        },
        error: function(XHR) {
            return afterDelete(th, false, XHR);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
jQuery('#domain-m-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['domain-m-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pagination','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed','selectableRows':1,'enableHistory':false,'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}','filterSelector':'{filter}','pageVar':'Domain_page'});
});
/*]]>*/
```